# how to make a child ignore effects from it's parent?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a multiple Vboxes/Hboxes inside a parent Vbox.  I have hide/show effects for the parent container, but I want to know if there is a way to make some of the children ignore this affect that they receive from their parent container.

Answer (score 4):

There's none. The DisplayList is an hierarchical structure, and every leaf object is displayed by using all the parameters from parent objects, including visibility, rotation and more. You may, however, enumerate children in your Vbox/Hbox to undergo the effect, and select (and manually apply) the desired effect only to those that should be hidden. Note that your Vbox/Hbox's visibility should remain true, and opacity at original value, should you use fade in/out effect, otherwise those children of your Vbox/Hbox will too get altered.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround by adding extra layer.

Then parent would have layers:

- New layer with parent background (apply effect here)
- your child (effect isn't applied as its parent has no effect)

Hope that helps.